# How can print string num?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Problem:
How can print string num? It seems that final statement cannot execute?
Question desciptions:
Notice that the number 123456789 is a 9-digit number consisting exactly the numbers from 1 to 9, with no duplication. Double it we will obtain 246913578, which happens to be another 9-digit number consisting exactly the numbers from 1 to 9, only in a different permutation. Check to see the result if we double it again!
Now you are suppose to check if there are more numbers with this property. That is, double a given number with k digits, you are to tell if the resulting number consists of only a permutation of the digits in the original number.

```
/* Have Fun with Numbers */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int book[10] = { 0 };
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char num[22];
    int temp = 0;
    scanf_s("%s", num, 1);
    // Length of numbers
    int len = strlen(num);
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        // Convert an ASCII value of a digit into an integer
        temp = num[i] - '0';
        // Add 1 each time read a digit
        ++book[temp];
        temp = temp * 2 + flag;
        flag = 0;
        if (temp >= 10) {
            temp -= 10;
            flag = 1;
        }
        // Convert an integer into an ASCII value of a digit
        num[i] = (temp + '0');
        // Subtract 1 each time generate a digit
        --book[temp];
    }
    int flag1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (book[i] != 0) {
            flag1 = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", (flag == 1 || flag1 == 1) ? "No\n" : "Yes\n");
    if (flag == 1) {
        printf("1");
    }
    printf("%s", num);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this like

```
    scanf_s("%s", num, 1);
```

You are reporting the buffer size as 1 to `scanf_s()` while the actual size is 22.

Use correct buffer size.

```
    scanf_s("%s", num, 22);
```

or

```
    scanf_s("%s", num, (unsigned)(sizeof(num) / sizeof(*num)));
```

Comment: Useful to explain why `unsigned` cast versus C spec's `rsize_t`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't think `scanf_s` in C standard is widely used. Cast to `unsigned` is used in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019).